# Shell script to test whether a directory exists and if not create it?

Tags: shell, directory, exists

I am trying to create a script to detect whether a directory exists, and if it does not, to create it.

How can I do that?

I did some digging and found a clue:

```
test -d directory
```

...will return `true` or `false` depending on whether the directory exists or not.

But how do I tie this together with `mkdir`?

Comment: Why bother testing?  Just do "mkdir foo 2> /dev/null".  If the directory exists, mkdir will fail and no harm done.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mkdir -p $directory` should do what you want.  The `-p` option will create any necessary parent directories.  If `$directory` already exists as a directory, the command does nothing, and succeeds.  If `$directory` is a regular file, it will remain untouched, and the command will fail with an appropriate error message.

Without the `-p` option to `mkdir`, the `test ... || mkdir ...` strategy can fail if `$directory` contains a '/', and some component of that path doesn't already exist.  The `test` is superfluous anyway, since `mkdir` does the same test internally.

Answer (score 3):

```
test ... || mkdir ...
```