# how to find particular directory exists within a directorty

Tags: bash, shell, unix

how to check whether a directory named such as "2012-02-06T00_17_25_25-06_00" exists inside a particular directory ? here the directory name is a combination of date and time.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shell script to test whether a directory exists and if not create it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937577/shell-script-to-test-whether-a-directory-exists-and-if-not-create-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just test it:

```
path=...
name=2012-02-06T00_17_25_25-06_00

if [ -d "$path/$name" ]
then
   echo "$path/$name exists and it's a directory"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find a directory `needle` that exists anywhere inside a parent directory `/haystack` (including as a sub-sub-sub... directory), you could try

`find /haystack | grep /needle/`

Comment: Or `find /haystack -type d -name needle`

Comment: -1 -name should be used like shown in the above comment instead of `find | grep`

Comment: Learn something every day. ;)